# I am having this issue when I tried to run the html file. what should I do now?

Tags: html, css

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/javascript: "file:///F:/smartData/Combine%20Project/Project/js/MyProject.js"

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using to link the script and what you have done to get to that point?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to re-save your project as a .js file ?
I mean try to write ".js" at the end of the file name when you save + take the ".js" file in the type file dropdown-menu.

Comment: I'm glad, you can validate(on the left of my answer) my response for other people searching the same thing ;)